# Spring MVC Validation messages translation

Tags: forms, validation, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am using Spring mvc app and I have implemented Spanish translation for the pages using internationalization. I have used the following code in my xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

 <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

All the labels and messages work except the validation messages. I am setting the validation messages in the validator class

```
errors.rejectValue("value1","valid.value1");
```

and in the properties file I have spanish, english texts in 2 files. But the

```
<form:errors path="value1" />
```

is not working properly. It is displaying the text as it is(I have some letters like n with tilda, so I tried with ñ) and it is not working.

My jsp page has the following on the top

```
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

        <head>
            <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    ................

    </head>

<body>

<form:errors path="value1" />

</body>
```

Do I need to add anything else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work. All I had to do was to add htmlEscape="false" to the . I did try that, but I added to the spring:message tag so it was not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem and realized that the rejectValue method doesn't actually translate the message, whereas if I use ValidationUtils everything works fine.

So if you need custom validations without ValidationUtils class then the only workaround that I found is to place  inside